# how to place image with in col with different image size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display something like this in a container with bootstrap 4. And it should be responsive.   How can I place images like that. I can make the hover effect but cant get the result like that. Thanks a lot[image: what I want]

Comment: does this help you: [Bootstrap 4 Masonry Layout](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/layout/bootstrap-masonry/)?

Comment: where is you code?

Comment: @Nishant instead of posting everywhere `where is your code?` you could actually be helpful. Point the suer to the guidelines and how to meet those guidelines. Just asking where their code is (espacially new or inexperienced users) can be considered rude.

Comment: ook !! but how someone help if they didn't find any code?

Comment: @Nishant like I said point them towards the guidelines and how to ask questions at SO. Help them to actually ask a good question like: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and add a [repro] ... Much more helpful to suers that dont know the guidelines! Besides of that, you could do the same that I did, point them in the right direction (in this case the user obviosly is looking for Masonry Layout but proberly didn't knew the name to search for)

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? => https://codepen.io/ashiishme/pen/KrVjpE

Comment: @tacoshy sure :)

Comment: Glad you like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using just basic css
the html section:

```
<div className="image-grid-light">
    <div className="imageContainer-light">
       <img className="imgs" src={image.url} alt={image.public_id}/>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS section

```
.image-grid{
    
    width: 95%;
    
    column-count: 3;
    gap: .5%;
    padding:2.5%;
    
    
}

.image{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    

}
```

and for responsiveness u can use @media and change column-count according to your need